# Sorting a ListView by a default column

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a xaml listview with an item source of an observable collection that has a payload of a 'Person' object.  Is there a way to get the listview to DEFAULT sort by a column if an item is added or removed from the collection?  So, say the Person object has a property of 'Age'.  When an item is added or removed, how to I get the listview to automatically sort by age?  I've been looking for a solution and I do not see one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just on addItem, and removeItem functions, add the following at the end :

```
SortDescription mySort = new SortDescription(Age, ListSortDirection.Ascending);
this.ListView1.Items.SortDescriptions.Clear();
this.ListView1.Items.SortDescriptions.Add(mySort);
```

This will add a sorting on "Age" Property.

Comment: That really helped.  I used a 'Sort Description' in the xaml in a resources tag, and it works perfectly.  Very clean solution.

Comment: @nikotromus I tried it also via XAML only solution, but it doesn't work for me - may I ask you to provide your solution as an example via separate answer? :)

Comment: It isn't needed to re-apply the `SortDescription` at each add item, as it works for newly added items automatically. At item remove, nothing has to be resorted, obviously. But if only a property of an item changes, the `SortDescription` has to be re-applied, to apply the sorting on the updated values!